# Mongodb installation failure to run mongod

Tags: mongodb

I have downloaded the newest version of mongodb and have moved and renamed the file to mongodb to the directory `usr/local/mongodb`. When I try to run mongod i get the following error

```
`./bin/mongod --help` for help and startup options
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8801 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=Hanss-MacBook-Air.local
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] git version: 329f3c47fe8136c03392c8f0e548506cb21f8ebf
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 dbexit: 
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Sun Apr 15 18:08:25 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: So, is there a `mongod.lock` file in the data directory?

Comment: there isnt but I got mongod to work after using sudo chown -R /data/db

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`sudo chown -R <your-username> /data/db`

Which user runs mongod? Are you running it with your regular login?

Comment: I got mongo to run by using sudo chown -R /data/db. Was wondering If i could get help for another problem. I tried running my rails project now with mongo >> rails server and i got this error:

Comment: Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /Users/hansarijanto/Desktop/Impact/ribbot/config/initializers/session_store.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_ribbot_session', :domain =>...

Comment: Create another stackoverflow issue for that. I'm not a rails guy.

Comment: This worked. The problem was permission to the /data/db directory.

Answer (score 4):

Same as "Joe Frambach's" but a little friendlier to cut and paste right away.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /data/db
```

Answer (score 1):

systemctl kicks in because the init-script for mongod sources this file like most others:

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

The block with chkconfig comments is used to define the config and pid-file:

```
# config: /etc/my-mongod.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/mongo/mongo.pid
```

But that pifile's path should match up with whatever you have in config's dbpath.
So this in /etc/my-mongod.conf

```
dbpath = /home/mongodb/2.0.5/data
```

Matches with this comment in /etc/init.d/mongod

```
# pidfile: /home/mongodb/2.0.5/data/mongod.lock
```

Comment: No sure to understand clearly what we are supposed to do unless this explanation is quite usefull

Answer (score 1):

got the same error, in Windows running with Administrator privileges solved the problem.

Comment: It is not recommended to run with admin privilege: the question addresses this particular statement

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db
```