# Journal files are present in journal directory, yet starting without journaling enabled

Tags: mongodb

I have started learning MongoDB and for which trying to install it on Ubuntu (which I recently shifted from windows). Facing issues to start it with `sudo service mongodb start`. Following are the logs:

```
Sun Aug  4 20:25:36.774 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
**************
Error: journal files are present in journal directory, yet starting without journaling enabled.
It is recommended that you start with journaling enabled so that recovery may occur.
**************
Sun Aug  4 20:25:36.774 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13597 can't start without --journal enabled when journal/ files are present, terminating
Sun Aug  4 20:25:36.774 dbexit: 
Sun Aug  4 20:25:36.774 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
```

Comment: following answer also helped ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798549/why-cant-i-start-the-mongodb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166612/mongodb-installation-failure-to-run-mongod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MongoDB has been shutdown forcefully then the journal files are not cleaned up. The warning is here so that you can decide whether you want to recover from a failure (recommended). For recovery to work, you need to start MongoDB with `--journal`. Journalling is turned on by default though so I expect your `/etc.mongodb.conf` file has a `nojournal=true` line. You can remove that one instead as well.

If you really don't care about recovering, then you can simply remove all the files under `/var/lib/mongodb/journal`—but realise that you might end up with broken data files.

Answer (score 3):

Remove journal files : everything under `/var/lib/mongodb/journal` if you want to disable journaling (not recommended) or use journaling: `journal=true` in config file or `--journal` from command line.